# В бустрап верстке внешняя ссылка

Tags: шрифты, css, bootstrap

Всем привет.

У меня на сайте с бустрап версткой в логах вижу внешнее обращение типа

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700
```

что мне очень не нравится, работая локально. Поиском в проекте нахожу, что ссылки в упакованных файлах типа

```
module.admin.stylesheet-complete.sidebar_type.collapse.min.css
```

И как лучше поступить?

1. Сохранить файл `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700` локально.
2. В упакованном файле поменять ссылку с `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700` на относитльный урл. Немного напрягает, что файл упакован...

Или есть лучшее решение?

Неудобство в том что работая локально из-за внешних ссылок сайт начинает заметно тормозить...

Comment: @mstdmstd, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что, открывая ссылку в разных браузерах, вы увидите разный результат, потому что гугл подрубает только те файлы шрифтов, которые поддерживает этот браузер, а не все сразу. И что вас, так сказать, "парит", я не понимаю. ) Вы подключаете шрифт с Google Fonts и юзаете их. В чем проблема? )

UPD. Скачайте шрифты с гугла и подключите их вручную.

Comment: @mstdmstd Проапдейтил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вам совершенно правильно ответили выше. Единственное, что можно сделать для повышения скорости загрузки страницы, - посмотреть, нужно ли Вам жирное и курсивное начертание данного шрифта, зайти в гуглфонтс и убрать лишнее.